# Using a variable in select top for a Insert Into

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having an issues in inserting rows when using a variable in the `SELECT`'s `TOP` clause. I get the following error:

> Msg 1014, Level 15, State 1, Line 571 A TOP or FETCH clause contains
>   an invalid value.

The variable is an integer, so that isn't the issue.  I am unclear why this error appears.

SQL query:

```
IF @TARGETNUM > @ACTUALNUM
BEGIN
SET @selectStatementNumber = @ACTUALNUM
END
ELSE
SET @selectStatementNumber = @TARGETNUM
--PRINT @selectStatementNumber

INSERT INTO @SPIDTEST
(
RN,
spid
)
SELECT TOP @selectStatementNumber
 RN = a.SPStatus 
,spid = a.NumSPIDsInState
from @SpidCount2 a
where a.lp = @licenceProvider and a.SPStatus = @Status
```

Comment: Well, have you checked the value in `@selectStatementNumber`? Perhaps it's `NULL` or a negative number? Or it's not an integer?

Comment: Exactly, check @selectStatementNumber variable before inserting and use parentheses at insert statement.

Comment: Yeah for some reason the first call was always a NULL. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP (ISNULL(@selectStatementNumber,0))
 RN = a.SPStatus 
,spid = a.NumSPIDsInState
from @SpidCount2 a
where a.lp = @licenceProvider and a.SPStatus = @Status
```

You need to add parentheses as above. And an `ISNULL` would be nice just in case.